# Creating a Tab Based Interface in MonoDroid with MvvmCross

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I'm new to Android development. I'm actually developing an app using MonoDroid and MvvmCross. I'm trying to create a basic tabbed interface. I saw this [example](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Views/HomeView.cs). However, it seems outdated (maybe I'm incorrect).

Does anyone know where I can see an example of a tabbed interface with `MvvmCross`? Currently, I have the following basic layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/theTabHost">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working properly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link points to 'master' which is the first version of mvvmcross.

For a newer version - v3 - try replacing the master with v3 - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Views/HomeView.cs

---

Another tabs sample is in the 'tutorial' there in v3 - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/Tutorial/Tutorial.UI.Droid/Views/Lessons/CompositeView.cs

A very modern sample - using fragments - is in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/TabView.cs

---

Sorry about the master (v1), vnext (v2) and v3 naming confusion - I will change these names soon.

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid. However, it seems like the first two links in your answer do not work. At the same time, I can't seem to reverse engineer them on the github site. Its almost like the directory structure has changed.

Comment: Sorry - not stupid - just the sample apps moved yesterday - all over to the https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/ - they will move again in the future to something in the https://github.com/MvvmCross account - all part of Mvx growing up

Comment: cool. also, i notice your name all of the place on this. thank you so much for your hardwork. this is a great framework from what I can tell.